# How to write the condition for passing a value to a cell in excel sheet if is not returning any null value?

Tags: java, excel, selenium

I need to pass a variable to an excel sheet cell.So how can I check whether it returns a null value or not.If it is having null value I need to give a alert message in the cell instead of the actual cell value.

```
            // Element fetching 

                       Element= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Form1']/table[3]/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/a")) ;
                       Email_ID = Element.getText();

                   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("E:\\ExcelRead.xls");
                        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
                        Sheet sh = wb.getSheet("Input");

        // File Handling
                        Row row = sh.createRow(ExcelRow);
            Cell cell_3 = row.createCell(2);
                        cell_3.setCellValue(Email_ID);
```

// File Handling

```
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("E:\\ExcelRead.xls");

                        wb.write(fos);

                        fos.close();

                        System.out.println("Excel File Written.");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if it is `null` or not. This could be applied to any object.

```
String value = null;

if(value != null)
{
 //do your logic
}
else
{
 System.out.println("Null Value");
}
```